Python - httpx or ThreadPoolExecutor
I have read a lot of things about ThreadPoolExecutor, httpx, requests and aiohttp on this website and others.
But, for a production script, I don't know if it's better to use httpx or ThreadPoolExecutor. Should I considerate to use aiohttp ? What is the best practice when you have to fetch more than 1000 devices ?
I've wrote this simple code below for example :
devices = ["device_1", ...]  # 1214 devices
session = requests.Session()

async def fetch_httpx():
    async with httpx.AsynClient() as client:
        await asyncio.gather(*[client.get(f"https://myserver.com/api/devices/{device}") for device in devices])


def fetch_threadpool():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor:
        responses = [executor.submit(session.get, f"https://myserver.com/api/devices/{device}") for device in devices]



I would expect an asyncio-based solution to achieve better performance than threads (there are articles etc. talking about aiohttp having much better performance for example). httpx and aiohttp are pretty similar, but I prefer aiohttp (and am a maintainer for it) because it tends to teach you to do the correct, more efficient solution first, and in every asyncio project I've worked on aiohttp was used as an indirect dependency even when the project wasn't using it directly (i.e. you probably will end up installing it regardless).

try different versions and you will see which one is the best for you.

I've made the same test with httpx (AsyncClient), ThreadPoolExecutor and aiohttp:
HTTPX ASYNC SESSION: Data fetched in 93.34 seconds.
THREADPOOLEXECUTOR: Data fetched in 71.80 seconds.
AIOHTTP SESSION: Data fetched in 71.72 seconds.
I think I will use ThreadPoolExecutor for the simply of use and maintenability.

I don't know if I've made some mistake or if the code could be better but based on this below :
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Token {token}"
}
device_url = "https://myserver.com/api/dcim/devices/"
cert_path = "cert/mycert.crt"

async def data_with_aiohttp():
    devices = ["dev_1", "dev_2", etc.]  # 1214 devices
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=cert_path)
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl_context=ssl_context)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, connector=connector) as session:
        tasks = [session.get(device_url, params={"name": device})for device in devices]
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def data_with_threadpoolexecutor():
    devices = ["dev_1", "dev_2", etc.]  # 1214 devices
    session = requests.Session(headers=headers, verify=cert_path)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=15) as executor:
        responses = [executor.map(fetch, [device for device in devices])]
    
    def fetch(device: str):
        return session.get(device_url, params={"name": device})

async def data_with_httpx():
        devices = ["dev_1", "dev_2", etc.]  # 1214 devices
        timeout = httpx.Timeout(15.0, read=None)
        limits = httpx.Limits(len(devices),20,60)
        async with httpx.AsyncClient(headers=headers, verify=cert_path, limits=limits, timeout=timeout) as client:
            tasks = [client.get(device_url, params={"name": device}) for device in devices]
            responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

Results are :

HTTPX ASYNC SESSION: Data fetched in 93.34 seconds.
THREADPOOLEXECUTOR: Data fetched in 71.80 seconds.
AIOHTTP SESSION: Data fetched in 71.72 seconds.

